# Placing an empty div between jqGrid's Caption and The grid itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to put some custom items (filters inputs) between the Caption and the grid itself on the jqGrid.

Is this possible, I have searched the api and nothing jumped out at me that would enable this.

For now, I have simply removed the caption and just put an all the stuff I want above the grid (including an H2 for what I wanted the caption to be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the toolbar search:

1. Go here: http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
2. Click "New in 3.3"
3. Click "Multiple Toolbar search"
4. Click the magnifier icon on the grid's toolbar.

If that's more or less where you want to put your inputs, then you can look at the search source to see how it's done.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. i'll take a look and see what can be done.

Answer (score 1):

This should be trivial with native jquery methods like prepend, before or wrap. 
For example I was able to add a button after the header row in firebugs console like this:

```
$("#gview_list3 div:first").after("<button>foo</button>");
```

Comment: Oh definately, I was just wondering if the jqGrid had built in extensibilty for this before doing it natively with jQuery